# Remove space around title in TitledBorder

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, border, titled-border

How can I remove space around title in TitledBorder? I mean this red border
[image: red border]

piece of code:

```
Font f = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 14);
Map m = f.getAttributes();
m.put(TextAttribute.BACKGROUND, Color.yellow);
Font ff = new Font(m);
Border mb = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(20, 0, 0, 0, Color.yellow);
Border test = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(-2,-2,-2,-2);
Border mb6 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(mb, "Title", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP, ff, Color.DARK_GRAY);
mb6 = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(test, mb6);
Border mb2 = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 0, 0, Color.gray);
mb2 = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(test,mb2);
Border mb3 = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(mb6, mb2);
Border mb4 = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.gray);
Border mb5 = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(mb4, mb3);
modeSetPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
modeSetPanel.setBorder(mb5);
```

Comment: That red border is probably added to your JLabel. But you need to post the code drawing this window in order for us to help

Comment: Well, what I was expecting to see is a call to setBorder on your JLabel which accepts a border object. Is there a call to setBorder somewhere in your code?

Comment: I don't understand what JLabel you are talking about. "Title" is an element of TitledBoderder. Anyway, I do nothing with borders outside the code I've posted.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Is there a point in using so many borders and compound borders?

Comment: I need exactly the same look. If you know a way to do it using less number of borders - I would do that way.
Again it's not what I'm asking for.

Comment: @Natalia can you desribe more which space you want to remove?

Comment: I want to remove red border around word "Title"

Comment: @Natalia: it seems, that problem is not in the pasted code, see my "answer" below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not care about borders, you could add a JPanel inside your Settings Tab panel.
In this JPanel you add another, with BorderLayout. Inside the one with the BorderLayout add two JPanels: The north one is with yellow background and the center one is with a red background. Just add a JLabel that says "Title" to the yellow JPanel and your controls to the red one.

This red border around the label is gone.

Here is an example without any borders and in the Nimbus look & feel:

[image: Sample...]

Answer (score 2):

In fact this is not an answer, but images in comments are not possible...

I tried this code:

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class RedBorderProblem extends JFrame {

    public RedBorderProblem() {
        final JPanel modeSetPanel = new JPanel();

        final Font f = new Font( Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 14 );
        final Map m = f.getAttributes();
        m.put( TextAttribute.BACKGROUND, Color.yellow );
        final Font ff = new Font( m );
        final Border mb = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder( 20, 0, 0, 0, Color.yellow );
        final Border test = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder( -2, -2, -2, -2 );
        Border mb6 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder( mb, "Title", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP, ff,
                Color.DARK_GRAY );
        mb6 = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder( test, mb6 );
        Border mb2 = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder( 1, 0, 0, 0, Color.gray );
        mb2 = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder( test, mb2 );
        final Border mb3 = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder( mb6, mb2 );
        final Border mb4 = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder( 1, 1, 1, 1, Color.gray );
        final Border mb5 = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder( mb4, mb3 );
        modeSetPanel.setBackground( Color.red );
        modeSetPanel.setBorder( mb5 );

        this.add( modeSetPanel );

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main( final String[] args ) {
        new RedBorderProblem();
    }

}
```

and the result is

[image]